# How can I create to my own setup.exe file in C#?

Tags: c#, installation

I'm developing an application using the C# programming language. How can I create to my own setup file in C# ?I don't want a commercial software. How can I do that?

Comment: Setup file? Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: There's [lots of resources about this on the Internet.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=35&gs_id=3p&xhr=t&q=creating+an+installer+visual+studio)  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Robert Harvey- I know how to create custom installers in Visual Studio‏.I want to create create to my own setup file in C#.

Comment: So,I want to develope to my own setup.exe in C#.

Comment: If what you're asking is "how to create a custom .exe for setup without using an existing setup framework", the short answer is "don't".

Comment: @Reinderien - What is the reason?

Comment: Because all of the setup project types output a setup.exe for you, and it is generally a bad idea to reinvent the wheel when someone else has done it professionally and fairly completely.

Comment: @Selo Basically, frameworks have done all of the hard work for you, and have developed the code that will make your setup file look professional and operate without bugs. If you write your own, it will take much more time and debugging, and won't be as high-quality.

Comment: Okay,thanks for your all answers.Finally,Where do i need to start to develope to my own setup.exe?

Comment: You need to learn how MSI works.  Hard to give links, nobody does this.  If you just want to get the feeling that you made your own then use WiX, http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new [Setup Project](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c#-application-visual-studio-setup-project/)

Answer (score 2):

Try the Nullsoft installer: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

In the File menu, click New->Project, and then in the dialog select Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment in the tree on the left.  Select InstallShield LE or Visual Studio Installer, as you prefer.

Personally I'd recommend Visual Studio Installer->Setup Wizard for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do that in Visual Studio by going New Project -> Other Project Type -> Setup and Deployment Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely determined to write your own .exe that's compatible with the Microsoft installer stuff, then you pretty much need to read this chapter cover-to-cover:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28v=VS.85%29.aspx