# How to create setup of c# project that is using third party Dll's

Tags: c#, installation, publish

Could anybody provide a method on how to setup a C# project, if you want to give your project to others.

Comment: Do you mean the source code or the final product? If the final product, then if it's a small one just give them all the files from the bin/release folder. Otherwise... google is your friend.

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=How+to+create+setup+of+c%23+project&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=wcW&hl=tr&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=C%23+setup+project&oq=C%23+setup+project&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30l3.10266.15144.1.15300.20.14.2.4.4.0.177.1478.9j5.14.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.yfqoRKcQHKY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.Yms&fp=26ebc9e6554a15ad&biw=1920&bih=950

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884327/how-can-i-create-to-my-own-setup-exe-file-in-c or http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/#-application-visual-studio-setup-project/

Comment: Is this a web application or a client application?

Comment: http://bit.ly/10wktJe

Answer (score 1):

If you have a normal desktop application, Setup Projects in Visual Studio have been discontinued. In VS 2012, there no longer is such a project type.

The [Wix toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) is pretty powerful, but not as intuitive for simple projects. They have [tutorials](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial) available. A lot of reading, but it's one of the best options if you don't want to downgrade to VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Publish` your project.

1. Right Click on your project file, select publish option and compleate
   the publish wizard.
2. Publish folder will get created in the folder you made for c#
   project.
3. In that folder your setup will be there.

When you complete that setup., you will be able to find your project in control panel.

Can also go through [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c#-application-visual-studio-setup-project/) link for other options.

Hope its helpful.